# AttributeError: module 'discord.ui' has no attribute 'TextInput'

Tags: python, discord

Error Code

```
class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title='Test'):
    name = discord.ui.TextInput(
    label='Test',
    placeholder='Test',
)
```

Error Message

```
class MyModal(discord.ui.Modal, title='Test'):
name = discord.ui.TextInput(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'discord.ui' has no attribute 'TextInput'
```

The current Python version is 3.11. What part should I change?
I'm looking into modals these days, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: maybe you are looking for `discord.ui.text_input`?

Comment: Or this? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=discord%20ui#discord.TextInput

Comment: what is your `discord` package version?
based on the docs here it is new in version 2.0 - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=textinput#discord.ui.TextInput

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using the most up to date version of discord.py since iirc TextInput and Modal's are a fairly new feature. Try retyping the code out manually and seeing if that works. Looking at the discord.py examples TextInput is a valid reference and since you are able to inherit from the discord.ui.Modal I am assuming you are using `import discord`. If that doesn't work check out the [example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/modals/basic.py) (if you haven't already)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
name = ui.TextInput()
```